# Powershell split string on multiple conditions

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a csv file where I am extracting a first and last name from a column, to seperate them in their own columns.

So given the string:

```
'John Doe - Generic- Random'
```

I would use the `split(" ")` to extract the first and last name

```
$string = 'John Doe - Generic- Random'
$firstName = $string.split(" ")[0]
$lastName = $string.split(" ")[1]
```

## First Issue

I found an issue where after the last name, sometimes the string does not have a space. For example

```
$string = 'John Doe-Generic-Random'
```

How would I get the last name `Doe` with out the rest. How can I apply the split for two conditions of `" "` and `"-"`

## 2nd Issue

Some strings only have a first name. For example...

```
$string = 'John - Generic - Random
```

How can I assign the last name as $null if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is working...

```
$string = 'John Doe - Generic- Random'
$firstName = $string -split {$_ -eq " " -or $_ -eq "-"}
$firstName[0]

$lastName = $string -split {$_ -eq " " -or $_ -eq "-"}
$firstName[1]
```

If there is no last name, it will be blank in the column Last Name.

If there is a last name but no space between the lastName-Info, it will exclude the -Info and add the lastName to the Last Name Column.