# I'm trying to clean up a script I have by trying to make it build the folder structure based on the file name

Tags: regex, powershell, split

I currently have a powershell script that I move files to specific folders based on the file names. The top of the script starts with setting a variables for the destination path where a certain group of files should go:

```
$FileName = "path to where files with that name go"
```

Then I read in the contents of the entire directory of files recursively into a variable:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $FileFolder -File -Recurse
```

Then I have a bunch of lines of the same command for matching and moving:

```
$Files | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'some name' } | Move-Item -Destination "$Variable-set-above" -Force
```

It was fine when it was 10 or 20 matches, but with more and more files being added and needing to be organized, I want to see if I can clean up the script by having it build the destination folder structure based on the file name instead of having a line for every match case, and a line for every move.

I was looking into `Split-Path`, regex `-split`, `String.split()`, and some other options, and I think I'm close, but I can't find an example anywhere of where someone takes the first portion of the file name, up to a certain couple of characters, keeping the first part, and excluding the rest. Kind of like a `Split-Ignoresecond` or something like that.

I'm testing doing this first before modifying my main script, I have this so far:

3 files in a folder named `Test.One.File.D0001.txt`, `Test.Two.File.D0001.txt`, and `Test.Three.File.D0001.txt`.

My test script:

```
$Testfiles = Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt
$Testfiles.replace('.',' ') -split "D0"
```

Which gives me an output of:

```
Test One File
001 txt
Test Three File
001 txt
Test Two File
001 txt
```

It's weird that it's not in the right order, but I envision that I'd be just dealing with 1 file at a time anyway so that won't matter.

What I'd like to do is read in a file name, ignore the "001 txt" part, use the first part of the filename to build the last part of a destination path for the file move, and then move the file to that destination. I could use `Split-Path -Leafbase` but I can't figure out the syntax for it to not give me an error, and I'd still be left with part of the filename I don't want.

Say I have a file called `One.Two.ThreeD0001` that needs to go to `D:\Files\Onestwosthrees`. I want my script to read in the files from a folder, and then process the file `One.Two.ThreeD0001.txt` so that all that's left is "One Two Three", stick it in a variable like `$SplitFile`, then move the file to a folder built from the filename like `D:\Files\Onestwosthrees\$SplitFile`.

There's further parsing I want to do, but if I can get this part down I can figure out the sub parsing I need.

Some sources I've looked at so far for clues are:

https://superuser.com/questions/817955
and
https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/

Comment: can you put syntax highlighting on your code samples? Ping me when you've put it in

Comment: @Isaac I'm not sure how to ping you, I clicked your name and there wasn't a way to send you a message that I could see. Also I can't seem to edit my post, so I'm not sure how to add syntax highlighting after the fact. My test script is just 2 lines, starting with $Testfiles, I'm not sure why the forum stuck them on the same line. Same with the output of the script, the output should all be on their own line.

Comment: @Squirreljester you should be able to edit your own posts, but I've made the formatting changes for you.

Comment: @Nacimota Thanks! I see the little hidden edit button on the post, but how'd you add the script stuff?

Comment: @Squirreljester if you indent code with four spaces, it will be formatted as code with syntax colouring. For inline code blocks `like this` you just surround the text with backticks `\`like this\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you were pretty much there:

```
cd "C:\Users\users\Downloads\StackTesting"

$testFiles = Get-Childitem -Include *.txt

foreach ( $item in $testfiles ) {
    $directory = ($item.name.replace('.', '') -split "D0")[0]

    ## check if folder exists, if not create
    if (!(Test-Path "C:\Users\user\Downloads\StackTesting\$directory")) 
    { 
       New-Item -Type Directory "C:\Users\users\Downloads\StackTesting\$directory"
    }
    ELSE
    {
        Write-Host "Folder exists"
    }

    ## Move item to folder
   Move-item $item.fullname -Destination "C:\Users\users\Downloads\StackTesting\$directory"

}
```

This is how i got your directory names:

```
$directory = ($item.name.replace('.', '') -split "D0")[0]
```

Changed from a space to no space as your examples at the bottom didn't have spaces.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! So when you assign the results of a split it automatically ignores what comes after where you split? Or is that what the [0] is for, is that a signifier for how many characters to keep? And the bottom example was a mistype by me, I need a space, but thank you for being thorough. :)

Comment: Not a problem and the split function puts each split into an element of an array so the [0] signifies the first element in the array.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait in responding, I've been super busy. Thanks again!

Also, out of curiosity, can you split it into more than 1? Like doing a `-split "File","D0"` and then choose which to use with the number in the brackets like `[0]` would be the first part, `[1]` the second, and `[2]` the third? I'm just trying to understand what it's actually doing.

Comment: Yes you can, you would use -split {$_ -eq "D0" -or $_ -eq "File"} see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915310/powershell-split-string-on-multiple-conditions